# Customising spacing and text elements in Gantt charts using pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm having great difficulty figuring out how to customise the Gantt charts using the pgfgantt package. There are two things I want to do:

1. Have the ability to add text under the labels of the main gantt labels
2. Adjust the vertical spacing

I had thought that you can use `\ganttalignnewline` to create a newline in a label. So for example:

```
\ganttbar[bar label node/.append style={align=right}]{Task 1 \ganttalignnewline This is a new line}{1}{2}
```

This is fairly fine for my purposes, but the real difficulty comes from trying to adjust the height of the individual cells. I had thought that you could do this via:

```
y unit chart=0.4cm
```

but now the problem is that the new text elements are not respected. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit chart=0.4cm]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar[bar label node/.append style={align=right}]{Task 1 \ganttalignnewline This is a new line}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following picture.

[image: Picture of poor spacing]

What I would really love is the ability to add TiKZ nodes or the like under each Gantt item.

Comment: Given that the bar labels etc. are nodes, you can add labels to them: ```\ganttbar[bar label node/.append style={align=right, label={[draw,red]below:foo}}]{Task 1}{1}{2} \\```. Alternatively give the label nodes a name with `bar label node/.append style={name=foo}`, and add nodes or whatever relative to them: `\node [below] at (foo.south) {bar};`. But that doesn't solve the trickier problem of the spacing. Increasing the spacing between every line is easy, just change the `y unit chart`, but I don't know how to make individual adjustments.